# kafka + why details about the retentions bytes are not displayed from kafka –describe

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running Kafka cluster with 3 nodes , `Kafka 0.11.0`.

We have set a global as well as a per-topic *retention in bytes*,

See relevant configs below:

```
server.properties

log.retention.hours=48
log.retention.bytes=6400000000
log.segment.bytes=10485760
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
confluent.support.metrics.enable=true
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
confluent.support.customer.id=anonymous
delete.topic.enable=true
auto.create.topics.enable=false
log.flush.interval.ms=10000
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=2000
log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=2000
log.flush.interval.messages=20000
queued.max.requests=1000
producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
num.replica.fetchers=1
min.insync.replicas=1
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
inter.broker.protocol.version=1.0
log.message.format.version=1.0
```

the strange thing is when we run `kafka –describe` , in order to verify the `retention.bytes` values from output then we get the following

we can see that `Configs:` get null

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper zk-01:2181/kafka --describe --topic stg_logtopic
    Topic:stg_logtopic    PartitionCount:12       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
            Topic: stg_logtopic   Partition: 0    Leader: 4       Replicas: 4,5,6 Isr: 4,5,6
            Topic: stg_logtopic   Partition: 1    Leader: 5       Replicas: 5,6,1 Isr: 5,1,6
            ...
```

While expected output should be something like this

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper zk-01:2181/kafka --describe --topic stg_logtopic
    Topic:stg_logtopic    PartitionCount:12       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:retention.bytes=6400000000
            Topic: stg_logtopic   Partition: 0    Leader: 4       Replicas: 4,5,6 Isr: 4,5,6
            Topic: stg_logtopic   Partition: 1    Leader: 5       Replicas: 5,6,1 Isr: 5,1,6
```

Why the details about `retention.bytes=6400000000` , are not displayed from `kafka –describe` ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How did you create the topic?

Comment: with kafka cli - the ordinary way

Comment: can you share that command?

Comment: kafka-topics -create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 100 --topic test-test

Comment: what you think about - why the retention not appears from described ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When describing topics using this tool, you only see the configurations that have been overriden. All other configurations, where the broker default is applied, are not listed.

You can override configuration at the topic level when:

- creating it: for example `kafka-topics.sh -create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 100 --topic test --config retention.bytes=12345`
- altering it: for example `kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name test --alter --add-config retention.bytes=12345`

In these cases, when describing the topic, you will see its configs:

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost --describe
Topic:test  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:retention.bytes=12345
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

If you want to see all configurations including the broker default, you need to use the `kafka-configs` tool and Kafka 2.5. For example (I truncated part of the output as it's pretty long):

```
./bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --entity-type topics --entity-name test --describe --all

All configs for topic test are:
  compression.type=producer sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:compression.type=producer}
  leader.replication.throttled.replicas= sensitive=false synonyms={}
  message.downconversion.enable=true sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.downconversion.enable=true}
  min.insync.replicas=1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:min.insync.replicas=1}
  segment.jitter.ms=0 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  <truncated>
  ...
```

Comment: since I am using kafka version 0.1 do you know what it the right syntax with kafka-configs.sh ......??

Comment: for example if I run kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --entity-type topics --entity-name test --describe --all , then we get

Comment: Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: all is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)

Comment: about what you said - "creating it: for example" and "altering it: for example" , as you know this configuration mayne works well but after we restart the kafka then the retention configuration will read back from server.properties

Comment: I don't think you can retrieve all configs with 0.11. You should really upgrade to a newer release, 0.11 is now very old.
If you create a topic with configs or alter it, the configurations is kept even if you restart brokers.

Comment: just one more note - this - kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name test --alter --add-config retention.bytes=12345 , is also support kafka version 0.1?

Comment: and what is the diff about create retention VS alter it?

Comment: if you create a topic with some configs or alter it after creation, it's the same.